# IndexError: Index out of Bounds error

Tags: python, nltk, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using NLTK's FreqDist object to make a cPickle file. However, for some reason, I encountered an index out of bounds error for line 3 ("cutoff...")

```
words = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]
freq = nltk.FreqDist(words)
cutoff = scoreatpercentile(freq.values(),15)
vocab = [word for word,f in freq.items() if f > cutoff] 
cPickle.dump({'distribution':freq,'cutoff':cutoff},open('freqdist_2.pkl',WRITE))
```

the error reads that

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 1419, in scoreatpercentile
score = _interpolate(values[int(idx)], values[int(idx)+1],
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

This code works perfectly fine on other computers...I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: What is the function `scoreatpercentile`?

Comment: How many items are in freq.values()?   ...```len(freq.values())```

Comment: ```scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile()``` isn't that complicated, you can look to see what it does, it is in stats.py which on my machine is at Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats.

Comment: ```freq.values()``` must be empty or contain only one item.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to debug what's in `nltk.FreqDist(words)` before you send it to scipy's `scoreatpercentile` function.

If you want a simpler way to get scoreatpercentile, here's an example:

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

words = "this is a foo bar bar bar bar black black sheep sentence".split()
sublist = "foo bar black sheep sentence".split()
words = [i for i in words if i in sublist]

word_freq = FreqDist(words)
cutoff = 15*sum(word_freq.values())/float(100)

vocab = [word for word,f in word_freq.items() if f > cutoff]

print vocab
```

[out]:

```
['bar', 'black']
```